# Program closing before it's really finished

Tags: c#, command-line-tool

I have a program with two modes: GUI & Just Run. GUI loads a WPF form and lets me adjust settings, while Just Run loads said settings and just... well... runs.

It's a glorified, customizable tool to batch-move files.

The problem: The "log" doesn't finish. It seems like it's still writing while the program closes, thus cutting off the end of the log.

Main App body:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        if (!e.Args.Contains("-gui"))
        {
            Process.SettingsPopulate();
            Process.WriteLogHead();
            Process.MoveFiles();
            Process.WriteLogEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
        }
        this.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Real simple. If command-line has -gui, it loads WPF... else it just runs.

```
    public static void WriteLogEnd()
    {
        foreach (var log in from i in Items
                            where i.Used == false
                            let build = new StringBuilder()
                            select build.AppendFormat("{0, -12} > {1} > Not Found", _time, i.FileName))
        {
            Logs(log);
        }

        Logs("");
        Logs("Fin.");
    }
```

Logs is a simple "Write to Console, Write to file" method. I iterate thru my list of processed files, finding items that aren't used... aka "not found". Before it ends the list, and write Fin, it closes.

Has me perplexed. How can I stop the file from closing before WriteLogEnd finishes (Since, afaik, it shouldn't be able to end before then anyways).

Comment: Are there any threads being used?

Comment: No threads. I'll edit to add the write method, as short as it is when I'm near the code again lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Logs is a simple "Write to Console, Write to file" method.

If it writes to File, add a Logs.Close() or something. You have to close a FileStream to flush its cache.

Comment: Wouldn't it flush on exit of the application?

Comment: Hrm... don't think I have a StreamWriter.Close anywhere. I'll have to try that, didn't think it would just "flush" stuff

Answer (score 2):

Run it in command line mode in a debugger to see if an exception is being thrown, or put a try..catch around the code in your OnStartup routine.

If an exception goes unhandled in any thread of a process, the entire process is terminated abruptly.

Also make sure you are closing any files or streams that you are writing the log to.  Most file I/O is buffered these days, and if you don't close the stream correctly the last buffer's worth of data may not be committed to the output device.